# Assigning different, but related, objects to one variable

Tags: c#, object

I'm new to C# and my OOP knowledge is sadly dated. Here's something I am flailing at right now.

I am using an external class library that uses 3 different flavors of the same class. I'd like to be able to store these in a generic name because they do have properties in common. I'm just not sure how to do this.

Sample:

```
using ExternalStuff.Defining.GenericFieldCriterion;

foreach (Criteria c in criterion)
{

     if (c.type.ToLower() == "date")
     {
                    DateFieldCriterion thisCrit = new DateFieldCriterion();
                    thisCrit.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(c.operand);
     }
     else if (c.type.ToLower() == "string")
     {
                    StringFieldCriterion thisCrit = new StringFieldCriterion();
                    thisCrit.Value = c.operand;
     }
     else if (c.type.ToLower() == "numeric")
     {
                    NumericFieldCriterion thisCrit = new NumericFieldCriterion();
                    thisCrit.Value = Convert.ToDouble(c.operand);
     }
     else
     {
             // bleargh.
     }  
 //=================================================================================== 
 // Of course, here's the issue... I want to set a property of thisCrit... but it is
 // out of scope (see next line):
 //=================================================================================== 

     thisCrit.SomeProperty = "Hello!"; // <<< No workie
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, I want to set properties on thisCrit no matter what subclass type it is, outside of the block where it is defined. Or else some other way to do this. There's a lot of processing that is going to happen on that, and I hate to repeat it for each subclass.

Comment: And the question is.. ?

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here.

Comment: lol @lazyberezovsky I think just guessing he want to save a list of those 3 types what he hae

Comment: If your using a libary by someone else the property types might be private and you wont have access to them

Comment: I want to be able to set thisCrit to one of: DateFieldCriterion, StringFieldCriterion, or NumericFieldCriterion. However, I don't know how to do that and be able to use thisCrit outside the scope of the block where it is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public class Criterion<T>
{
  public T Value {get; set;}

  public string SomeProperty {get; set;}

}
```

**Edit**

> I want to be able to set thisCrit to one of: DateFieldCriterion,
>   StringFieldCriterion, or NumericFieldCriterion. However, I don't know
>   how to do that and be able to use thisCrit outside the scope of the
>   block where it is set.

Then just create a common interface with the common properties

```
public interface ICriterion
{
   string SomeProperty {get; set;}
}

public class StringFieldCriterion : ICriterion
{
   public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
   public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ICriterion thisCrit = null;

if (c.type.ToLower() == "string")
{
    thisCrit = new StringFieldCriterion { Value = c.operand };
}
//other if/else blocks

thisCrit.SomeValue = "Hi";
```

**Edit 2**:

So, all three criterions inherit from `QueryCriterion`, right? So that means you should be able to assign a concrete criterion object (like `StringFieldCriterion`) to a variable of type `QueryCriterion`. Like this:

```
QueryCriterion thisCrit = null;

if (c.type.ToLower() == "string")
{
    thisCrit = new StringFieldCriterion { Value = c.operand };
}
//other if/else blocks

thisCrit.SomeValue = "Hi";
```

Comment: I'm not sure. What is <T>? Does that represent any of the 3 subclasses?

Comment: @Panamah That's called a "generic type parameter". Google for "c# generics". Have you used a generic list before? The class is named `List<T>`, where `T` is the type of the objects allowed be placed on the list.

Comment: But check out the code I provided in my updated answer, it fits your scenario better. Generics is not what you need after all.

Comment: Neat! Let me give that a shot... I will report back.

Comment: Do those common properties (not parameters) have a common type? For example, all your classes have a `Value` property, but they have different types (one is a string, the other is a double, etc), so they're not really common properties. Also, show us the code that's not working.

Comment: So... I think the issue is this. There's already a Date/Numeric/StringFieldCriterion classes defined by the external library I'm referencing. So these classes are overriding those. I'm not getting data from that external lib now. I need my solution to sort of encapsulate those classes into one thing I can reference -- if that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize they were in an external assembly, my bad... do you have access to that library? can you modify its code? If not, do they inherit from a common abstract class/do they implement a common interface?

Comment: I can't modify it. :(

I'm sure they're just inherieting from a common interface. Let me look at the docs.

Comment: `public class DateFieldCriterion : QueryCriterion, 
 IDateFieldCriterion`

That is how that is defined in the docs. Then
`public class StringFieldCriterion : QueryCriterion, 
 IStringFieldCriterion
`
and 
`public class NumericFieldCriterion : QueryCriterion, 
 INumericFieldCriterion
`

Comment: Alright, so it looks like you could be using the `QueryCriterion` defined in the external assembly instead of the `ICriterion` I suggested. `QueryCriterion` _should_ have some of the common properties, depends on how the author decided to do it.

Comment: Can you modify your example to explain? I'm not quite smart enough to grok what you just said.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, it gets us closer, but apparently the Value is defined in each subclass because it is different for each of the three types. (DateTime, string, and double). Any ideas? (BTW: Thanks so much for your help)

Comment: That makes sense. The `Value` property is not common to all those subclasses - so each class has its own. What's the issue?

Comment: The reason I thought it didn't work is that I tried to this this: `thisCrit = new DateFieldCriterion(); thisCrit.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(c.operand);` That didn't work, but setting the Value in the constructor does work. Woot!

Comment: Lol cool. By the way, those are called "object initializers", they're pretty handy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Awesome! I've learned bundles already today and it isn't even noon.

Thanks again!

Comment: One last question on this. Is there anyway to directly access those class values? For instance, I cann't do this: `if (thisCrit.Value == 99)` because the parent class (QueryCriterion) doesn't have Value defined. I'm a little stuck because I need to access one of those interior values that I initialized when I created the object.
Think way, way back to my old-school C days, I'd use a cast or something like that.

Comment: If you already know which type of object you're dealing with, you can do: ``if (((NumericFieldCriterion)thisCrit).Value) == 90)``